# C++ std::copy from std::deque to std:;set

Tags: c++, stl, set

I have a class with "array of array" private member represented as:

```
std::deque<std::deque<SomeClass> > someArray_;
```

Also this class have a public method which allows to receive all unique `SomeClass` instances, containing in `someArray_`. Unique for `SomeClass` instances means different by at least one of several class members. I decided to use `std::set` for that purpose. This method has prototype like following:

```
std::set<SomeClass> getAllUniqueInstances() const;
```

In this method implementation I use following construction to populate `std::set`:

```
std::set<SomeClass> allUniqueInstances;
for(auto it = std::begin(someArray_); it != std::end(someArray_); ++it){
    std::copy((*it).begin(), 
              (*it).end(),
              std::inserter(allUniqueInstances, allUniqueInstances.end()));
}
```

`operator<()` is defined for `SomeClass` class. As a result my `std::set` is populated, but huge amount of instances is missed. Modyfing `operator<()` for `SomeClass` class, alters situation, but breaks desirable sorting order. How in this case `std::copy` determines whether considerable instance is unique?

**UPD**: source code for `SomeClass`

```
class SomeClass{
    private:
        uint32_t from_;
        uint32_t to_;
        double capacity_;
        double flow_;
    public:        
        ...
        bool operator<(const SomeClass& rhs) const;
        ...
    };
```

I want `SomeClass` instances to be ordered in set by `from_` member:

```
bool SomeClass::operator<( const SomeClass& rhs ) const{
    if(this->from_ < rhs.from_)
        return true;    
    return false;    
}
```

Comment: If you were to write a `operator==` for `SomeClass` what would you consider to be the attributes necessary ? Just `from_` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not `std::copy` who decides whether instances are unique, but `std::set`. The logic is something like

> (A < B is false) and (B < A is false)

So the criterion that defines the ordering also defines the "uniqueness". It seems like `std::set` is the wrong data structure for this problem, or your ordering criteria are either incorrect (as in not implementing strict weak ordering), or too broad to suit the problem (as in, you order based on a small number of attributes when you could use more).

Here is an example of a lexicographical comparison using more attributes than you currently have:

```
#include <tuple> // for std::tie

bool SomeClass::operator<( const SomeClass& rhs ) const
{
  return std::tie(from_, to_, capacity_, flow_) < std::tie(rhs.from_, rhs.to_, rhs.capacity_, rhs.flow_);
}
```

Comment: +1  Enforcing that can get tedious when consuming multiple values in a `operator<()` and I suspect that is indeed the issue here.

Comment: @WhozCraig or it could be as trivial as there are indeed many duplicates for a correct ordering.

Comment: In fact i have exactly one duplicate for every unique instance

Comment: Absolutely. Without knowing the comparator and the underlying data, its speculative either way, but based on history, I'd hedge a bet on the former =P

Comment: @karven `SomeClass` instances with the same value of `from_` are duplicates.

Comment: @karven I see nothing wrong with that comparator, so (a) I'd lose the bet, and (b) if it is as you say, 50% of your items won't make it into the set (because as far as the set is concerned, *they're already there*).

Comment: @juanchopanza is it a good choice to update my `operator<()` to compare other class member if `from_` members is equal?

Comment: @karven exactly. I added an example, using C++11 tuples.

Comment: @juanchopanza once again, you prove I really need to spend time reviewing all the goodies added in 11. That thing makes life a *helluva* lot easier. Thank you!

Comment: @WhozCraig I would really struggle to write a lexicographical comparison with more than three attributes by hand, but I had been using the `tr1` or `boost` versions for a while. I take pride in my "laziness" :-)

Comment: @karven there is a *lot* going on under those expansions, so revel in the joy of juancho's laziness. Doing that by hand is a PITA, believe me.